# Executing document element clicks in order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, click

I have bunch of document element clicks in my JavaScript code. Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button1")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("button2")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("button3")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("button4")[0].click();
```

But they don't execute in order. I want every next to wait for every previous button click complete. I couldn't pass callback to those click functions. Is there any way? I'm quite new to JavaScript ecosystem.

Thanks.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to wrap every call in a setTimeout and execute them with a delay (1-10 should be long enough). But it is not a good style!

Comment: @Niklas Yeah, I know that. But I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for the previous button click to complete"? A button click is an instantaneous action. Do you mean that it should wait for the previous button's event listener to finish?

Comment: If that's what you want, the right solution is for the event listener to trigger the next click.

Comment: They will click in order. My guess is something else is happening behind the scenes that makes it not seem like they run in order. The real solution requires to know what the button clicks actually trigger and working with that directly.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's what I want to happen. I want to get the actual result after each click and then execute the next.

Comment: @epascarello I have this in chrome extension. I have no idea how they work behind the scenes.

Comment: Then the only thing you can do is use timeouts and hope it returns. If you have no access to the asynchronous code it triggers, there is nothing you can do. If something in the UI updates, you can listen for that. There is nothing you can do just with the click actions, you have to rely on something else.